# Imageview with rounded corners for android xml

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a simple imageview and just want to round the corners of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a library if you're willing to: [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

Bonus:

This is how I use it on my app:

`layout.xml`

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_user_photo"
    style="@style/AppWidget.CircleImageViewAppearance"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_user_photo" />
```

`styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppWidget.CircleImageViewAppearance">
    <item name="civ_border_color">@color/white</item>
    <item name="civ_border_width">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i will definitely try this out, can you tell me what to do in the java portion? or does this work for when i select i pic through gallery and replace it with the previous pic?

Comment: You just use `findElementById` and save it to an ImageView object. Then you can load an image to this ImageView normally.

Comment: I know but this method doesnt work for gallery intents